# How to create a desktop shortcut to work VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn

When I connect to my work vpn I go to the start menu > type "Connect to a network" and click the said option under "Control Panel".  I really dislike going through this procedure everytime.  It would be fantastic if I could actually link to my VPN so I can double click and just hit connect...or even double click and it automatically starts to connect.  Any idea if this is possible in win7?  This was REALLY easy in XP...

I thought I could link a shortcut to the exe if I could find it in task manager.  When I "go to process" in task manager it takes me to explorer.exe.  So, I popped open [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and looked for a child process for the VPN, no success.  I closed the vpn window and my process count stayed @70.  So I guess this thing is spawned as a thread inside of the explorer.exe process.  There's gotto be some way to launch it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Icon -> Control Panel-> Networking and Sharing Center-> Change Adapter Setting

Then it's just like XP. Right click on the VPN connection and say create shortcut or drag the icon to the desktop and it will create the shortcut.

Comment: Windows Icon -> Control Panel-> Networking and Internet > View Network Status and Tasks > Change Adapter setting = Win7 ulitmate